# An alias for a command to kill stopped jobs

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, alias

I wanted to add an alias to my .bashrc so that I could kill all stopped jobs with a command like `kill_stopped`. I am aware that `` kill `jobs -p` `` can be used to accomplish this but I'd rather have an easier-to-remember alias for convenience sake. So I added this line to my .bashrc:

```
alias kill_stopped="kill `jobs -p`"
```

However, when I run it I get a message about the usage of the kill command. To make sure it was being run properly I ran `` echo "kill `jobs -p`" `` in the shell and got back `"kill <some number>"` whenever I had a stopped process. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Can you post what you added in your bashrc file?

Comment: What makes you think that `kill \`jobs -p\`` will kill stopped jobs? That will only kill jobs launched from the particular shell you are running and it will kill _all_ of them, irrespective of if they're active or not. Is that really what you want? What exactly do you mean by "stopped"?

Comment: If you really want _stopped_ jobs, you want `jobs -p -s`.  The `-s` flag is a `bash` extension and won't necessarily work in other shells.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but you should use single quotes, not double quotes:

```
kill_stopped='kill `jobs -p` '
```

Backticks are expanded inside double quotes, so it was running `jobs -p` at the time you defined the alias, not when you used it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alias kill_stopped="kill \$(jobs -p)"
```

and to kill runnings jobs:

```
kill_stopped
```

If there are no running jobs you get a message about the usage of the kill.